# xpath: how to express text nodes?

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

consider:

```
text 1

text 2

text 3
```

how can you express the textnode in xpath ?

Comment: That is not xml or an xpath expression what do you mean

Comment: i want to select A text node.....text() gives you ALL text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know , all text in a node are collectively grouped up as a single text node. They are not hierarchical so there wont be more than 1 text node in any single element.

You might need to parse the text yourself using an [xpath string function](http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xpath_string_functions.cfm)

Comment: This is not entirely correct. All *consecutive* text nodes in a node are collapsed. If they are interspersed with other nodes, they are treated separately.